# mapDispatchToProps not working. this.props.getCategories is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props, dispatch

I am trying to get a list of categories from backend using react-redux
looks like things are fine unless the dispatch function calls.
I just used a tutorial from youtube in this [link](https://youtu.be/BmL8iaLMnQ0) by Traversy Media

**Reducer**

```
import { GET_CATEGORIES } from '../actions/types.js';

const initialState = {
    categories: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_CATEGORIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                categories: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```

**Action:**

```
import axios from "axios";

import { GET_CATEGORIES } from "./types";

//GET CATEGORIES
export const getCategories = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/categories/')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_CATEGORIES,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

**Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getCategories } from '../actions/categories';

export class Categories extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCategories();  //no error when comment this line
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>
                    Categories Component
                </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.categories.categories
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCategories })(Categories);
```

if I comment the line in the componentDidMount then page loads with an empty array in the redux store but if I try to call the action to actually get data, I get the following errors:

[Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getCategories is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvtBM.png)

***EDIT:***

I import Category component in **App.js** this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';
import {Categories} from './Categories';

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Categories />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

also I found I get the below warning from webpack:

```
WARNING in ./prj/frontend/src/components/Categories.js 63:17-30
export 'default' (imported as 'getCategories') was not found in '../actions/categories' (possible exports: getCategories)
 @ ./prj/frontend/src/components/App.js 27:0-42 45:42-52
 @ ./prj/frontend/src/index.js 1:0-35
```

Comment: How you import Categories, please edit the question and show it to us

Comment: I edited the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any problem with the provided code, my guess is that you wrongly imported a non connected component:

```
// WRONG, you import non-connected component
import {Categories} from 'Categories.js'

// Your default export is wrapped with connect
import Categories from 'Categories.js';
```

Comment: I the IDE added like your first line (however ./Categories instead of Categories.js)  and I changed to your second line and nothing changed

Comment: Oh I found that I was importing class itself, not connect!

Answer (score 1):

After I read the documentation about [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object) again, I think that an async action is not possible with connect's [object shorthand form](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form).The reason for this is that the object shorthand form assumes that the object contains `ActionCreator`s

> **Object Shorthand Form**
>
> mapDispatchToProps may be an object where each field is an [action creator](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/glossary#action-creator).

`ActionCreator`s must return an action. The action that they return is dispatched to the store. The `connect` method achieves this by using the [`bindActionCreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) method.

> **bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)**
>
> Turns an object whose values are action creators, into an object with the same keys, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly.

Since your `getCategories` is an **async function** it does not return an action. It can't return an action because the action needs the payload of the `Promise` from the axios call and because it doesn't return an action there is nothing that can be dispatched. That's why the object shorthand form doesn't work.

Here is a version that uses the `mapDispatchToProps` function that works.

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { Component } = React;

const initialState = {
    categories: []
}

const GET_CATEGORIES = 'getCategories';

function reducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_CATEGORIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                categories: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

const getCategories = (dispatch) => () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
       dispatch({
                type: GET_CATEGORIES,
                payload: data
            });
       }
      );
};

class Categories extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCategories();  //no error when comment this line
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>
                    Categories Component
                </h1>
                <p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.categories)}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.categories
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getCategories: getCategories(dispatch)  };
};

const ConnectedCategories = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Categories);

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState)

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedCategories/></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.1.1/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.4/react-redux.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I read the documentation again and now I guess I can answer your question and updated my answer.